# Trying to get property of non-object simple html dom in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display every row of table with [SIMPLE HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Plus add at the end of row 2 links

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    //Connection
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webapp");
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

    //Checks connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) { exit("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }

    //Selects content of DB
    $postContent = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=1");

    //Creates array from content
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($postContent);

    //Loads content as first element of array
    $html = str_get_html($result[0]);

    foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
        $temphtml = str_get_html($element->innertext);
        $tempico = $temphtml->find('a', 0)->innertext; //line #42
        echo "<tr>" . $temphtml . "<td><a href=\"delete.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Delete</a> // <a href=\"change.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Change</a></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

`$tempico` is number which is later used as url parameter. On line #42 I am trying to get it from between first `<a>` tag in row.

My problem is at line #42 where I get error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\control.php on line 42`

Is there any way I can do this better or to not get this error?

Here is html in database

```
<table class="tg-table-orange">
<tbody id="SK">
<tr id="47 387 131">
    <td><a href="link" class="ico">47 387 131</a></td>
    <td class="47 387 131">BARDOSA</td>
    <td>s.r.o.</td>
    <td>06.09.2013</td>
    <td class="47 387 131"><a class="button1" href="link">Zarezervuj</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `print_r($temphtml->find('a', 0));` and see what it has, before accessing its innertext

Comment: can you provide HTML structure?

Comment: @JensonMJohn Added html structre

Comment: In the HTML structure, I didn't find any anchor tags!

Comment: @JensonMJohn I am very sorry I posted wrong html now I posted html which is in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that if there was no `<a>` tag it returned error so I created IF in loop.

```
foreach($htmlSK->find('tr') as $element) {
    $temphtml = str_get_html($element->innertext);
    if(gettype($temphtml->find('a', 0)) == "NULL") {
        echo "<tr>" . $temphtml . "</tr>";
    } elseif(gettype($temphtml->find('a', 0)->innertext) == "string") {
        $tempico = $temphtml->find('a', 0)->innertext;
        echo "<tr>" . $temphtml . "<td><a href=\"delete.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Delete</a> // <a href=\"change.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Change</a></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this

HTML

```
<table class="tg-table-orange">
<tbody id="SK">
<tr id="47 387 131">
    <td><a href="link" class="ico">47 387 131</a></td>
    <td class="47 387 131">BARDOSA</td>
    <td>s.r.o.</td>
    <td>06.09.2013</td>
    <td class="47 387 131"><a class="button1" href="link">Zarezervuj</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

PHP

```
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
      foreach($element->find('td') as $td)
        {

                $temphtml = str_get_html($td->innertext);
                $tempico = $temphtml->plaintext; 
                break;

        }
        echo "<tr>" . $temphtml . "<td><a href=\"delete.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Delete</a> // <a href=\"change.php?ico=" . $tempico . "\">Change</a></td></tr>";
    }
```